# Constant issues with the Calliper

Tags: brakes, vw, brake-calipers

I have a VW Golf 2005 reg TDI 2.0. I am having to replace calliper one after another. The first time it was front passenger side, and then rear passenger side. Now I am replacing the front driver side, and I am wondering if there is an underlying issue I'm not aware of. When I bought the car it had 83k miles. Now it has 110k miles.

Regards

Comment: Consider this a lesson to have brake repairs done in pairs. If one side has failed, the other is likely on it's way out too. And it's probably better to have new parts on both sides to ensure even braking.

Comment: Why are you having to replace the calipers? What is going wrong with them?

Comment: @cory All other brakes were replaced at the same time, it's only the calliper that I changed alone as the faulty was one

Comment: sounds like it's just age, are the pistons seizing?

Comment: @JackM, i suggest you update your question with the actual symptoms you were having before replacing the calipers.

Comment: @cory - I know this is your thinking, but there's no real reason to replace in pairs unless there is a problem with the other. By your line of thinking, you could state you should replace all four on any given vehicle at the same time to ensure they are all working in accord. I'd suggest, they'll continue to work in accord as long as the caliper isn't sticking (retracts properly after braking) and isn't leaking. Any other reason is just overkill and quite possibly a waste of money.

Comment: What kind of failures? Leaks? (low quality caliper - or severely overheating the brakes) Caliper sticking? (grease it properly with every brake pad change)

Comment: failing as in break overheating, It started with front Left, then front right and back left. I was wondering is it age related? or is there any underlying issue I should be aware of

Comment: did replacing the calipers fix your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caliper failure typically means that a seal has gone bad, letting dirt in, and one of the sliding parts has worn down to the point where it's either stuck or leaking profusely. All moving parts wear eventually, but this happens prematurely when the calipers are not maintained during a brake service.

To maintain a caliper, it should be cleaned and regreased any time you replace pads or rotors. The rubber boots should be checked for wear and damage, and replaced if there is any. The bushings and sliding parts should also be checked for wear. Sometimes these are replaceable, sometimes you have to replace the whole caliper, it depends on the design.

This important step was probably skipped during the last brake job, and now you're seeing the result.